# Printing a Float Beyond Its Precision

Tags: python, floating-point, formatting, output, precision

When I run this code,

```
print('{:.15f}'.format(123456789.55555555555555555555555555555555555555))
print('{:.25f}'.format(0.5555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555))
```

I get this output:

```
123456789.555555552244186
0.5555555555555555802271783
```

Where do those extra digits come from(123456789.55555555`2244186`, 0.5555555555555555`802271783`) and why are they not zero?

I am guessing they are generated by the conversion algorithm and are meaningless, but I would like to have more info on this. It would be nice if the conversion algorithm made them zero.

Comment: Take a look at [Floating point](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point). Standard Python (aka CPython) uses [IEEE 754 double precision](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format#IEEE_754_double-precision_binary_floating-point_format:_binary64) for its `float` type.

Comment: So, I understand how a floating point number operates in general. But why does the conversion algorithm keeps on converting, when it ran out of bits to convert? A float has a limited precision, unlike a decimal.

Comment: Ah, ok. That's a better question. :) I'm not sure why the conversion routine keeps on going, converting garbage bits. It looks like it continues for around 53 digits, which is curious, given that there are 53 significant _bits_ in an IEEE 754 double. Try changing the format spec to `{:.63f}` on your second number & you'll eventually see a bunch of zeroes.

Comment: Just because you can type a float literal `0.555...` doesn't mean Python is storing *that* value exactly. It's converting it to the closest fraction with a denominator that is a power of 2, and the decimal expansion of *that* fraction is what you are seeing.

Comment: @chepner: Certainly. But that still doesn't explain those wacky digits above & beyond the call of duty. :) Eg, 0.2=1/5=3/15, so in hex that's 0.33333... It's understandable that it'll start producing rubbish after the 16th place, but why does the conversion routine bother spitting out rubbish for another 30-odd digits?

Comment: Given that you've requested it, Python has to produce *something* or raise an error. The relative error should be insignificant, so that's easier to deal with than handling an error. It's undefined behavior as far as I can tell.

Comment: If this is only *something*, and not meaningful, I would prefer zeros instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you try to store these values what is actually stored is the closest representable double precision binary floating point value. And that is what is being printed. So these extra digits are actually meaningful - they represent the actual value that is stored.

See [Rob Kennedy's useful web page](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~rkennedy/exact-float) which shows the closest representable floating point number to a given value. As you can see, [the closest double precision value to your first value](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~rkennedy/exact-float?number=123456789.55555555555555555555555555555555555555) is:

```
+ 1234 56789.55555 55522 44186 40136 71875
```

And the [closest double precision value to your second value](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~rkennedy/exact-float?number=0.5555555555555555555555555555555555555555555555) is:

```
+ 0.55555 55555 55555 58022 71783 25003 47867 60807 03735 35156 25
```

These values match what Python produces.

So, this is purely an issue of representability. More references on floating point:

- [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)
- [What Every Programmer Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://floating-point-gui.de/)
- [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Comment: OK, that makes sense. I guess. :)

Comment: So, one thing is for sure, Python and the [on line converter](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~rkennedy/exact-float) use the same conversion algorithm. I am still fuzzy on how they come up with these extra digits, math-wise. And why the algorithm gives up after about 53 digits, as *PM 2Ring* has shown.

Comment: It's the closest representable value. It's not a coincidence that Rob's page and Python do the same thing. This is governed by a standard IEEE754. Did you read the links I gave you so that you understand what that means. A double precision value has 53 binary bits of precision.

Comment: Yes, but 53 binary bits do not relate to 53 decimal digits. Or do they?

Comment: My answer is accurate. Did you read the links yet? Do you understand what numbers are representable? Can you find representable numbers that are closer? 53 decimal digits is a red herring. The first number has 34 decimal digits.

Comment: Numbers with more than 53 decimal digits *should* be closer, but I guess this is their arbitrary cutoff point.

Comment: No. It not arbitrary. Double precision binary floating point is not arbitrary. It has 53 binary digits of precision. And that's the cut off. If you want to understand this you'll need to really be clear on what is meant by representable, and how numbers are represented.

Comment: `print('{:.100f}'.format(0.1))` produces `0.1000000000000000055511151231257827021181583404541015625000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000` They stopped with 55 *decimal* digits after the decimal point. I bet `0.1` could be represented more precisely if they used more *decimal* digits. I am still trying to digest that last link that you provided.

Comment: It's not represented by decimal digits. It's represented by binary digits. 53 of them. Did you read the links I gave you yet? You still seem to think that 64 bits can hold an arbitrary amount of information. I'm just repeating myself now. Try to understand how these values are represented.

Comment: Ok, so the string representation would be more precise if they kept on converting instead of using trailing zeros. But they stopped at 55.

Comment: No. That's wrong. That value is exact. That's the closest double precision value to 0.1.

Comment: But why the claim that a 64-bit float can be represented exactly with 17 decimal digits?

Comment: Because a decimal digit has more information than a binary digit.

Comment: Yes, but it took them 55 decimal digits to represent `0.1`. I guess 17 decimal digits is enough for when you convert from a string to a float, but not the other way around?

Comment: 55 decimal digits are for the **closest** double precision value to 0.1. I don't think you are really getting this. I recommend that you read the links I gave you. Concentrate on how a number is represented.

Comment: I think I got it for the most part. `s='{:.100f}'.format(1/3); print(float(s)==float(s[:19]))` When converting from a string to a float, 17 significant decimal digits is enough, everything else is lost. But to represent a float in a string precisely, it may well take more than 17 decimal digits.

Comment: @coding4fun: Note that `2^-53` is a number with a lot of digits in decimal, although it is only one bit in the floating point value. Heck, `2^-10` is already `0.0009765625`, and that is also only one bit in a float. So you see exact values, and these have that many digits. This due to the fact that you are converting binary to decimal. If the exponent is not 0, then it gets even worse.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis You are not kidding. 2e-53 = 0.000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000020000000000000000615975242951574530368453090977309217149973291912142953202919462494985454702596019212913114791075752904401982724331737935330455258053916622884571552276611328125  That is __228__ places after the decimal point.

Comment: 2e-53 is not the same as 2^-53. I assume you meant the latter. <g>

Comment: 2^-53 = 0.00000000000000011102230246251565404236316680908203125 Slightly less impressive, but still a lot of digits. But I see your point that a single binary bit results in many decimal digits when we try to represent a binary number in decimal notation.

Comment: 2^-500 = 0.00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000030549363634996046820519793932136176997894027405723266638936139092812916265247204577018572351080152282568751526935904671553178534278042839697351331142009178896307244205337728522220355888195318837008165086679301794879136633899370525163649789227021200352450820912190874482021196014946372110934030798550767828365183620409339937395998276770114898681640625  A single set binary bit in the mantissa, but quite a number in the decimal notation.

Comment: Seems like you've got the hang of this now!